# How to convert Apache's `AllowOverride all` to nginx

Tags: apache, nginx, apache2, passenger

I have an Apache2 & Passenger site for Rails app, that uses following configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  DocumentRoot /var/www/site/public
  <Directory /var/www/site/public>
    AllowOverride all
    Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Is there an equivalent for nginx & Passenger site? Currently nginx responds to all requests in form `{ID}/action` with `404`. Here's the relevant part of nginx conf:

```
   location / {
      passenger_app_root /var/www/site;
      passenger_document_root /var/www/site/public;
      passenger_enabled on;
      try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
   }
```

There's no `.htaccess` file in the app.

Comment: There is nothing like `.htaccess` in nginx, so there is no reason to have AllowOverride directive.

Comment: Do you know what `try_files` do?

Comment: With try_files nginx actually looks for an existing file, and in your configuration, it returns a 404 error if it does not find the file.

Comment: Yes, I know how `try_files` works. It's just a bit magical how the should be passed to Passenger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passenger author here. There is no equivalent for 'AllowOverride all' in Nginx, and you don't need it either. All you need is a virtual host block with the 'root' pointing to your app's 'public' directory, and 'passenger_enabled on':

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name www.example.com;
   root /var/www/site/public;
   passenger_enabled on;
}
```

...as explained by [the official Passenger documentation's deployment instructions](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/deploy/nginx/deploy/ruby/).

`passenger_app_root` and `passenger_document_root` are automatically inferred for you from `root`. There is no need for `try_files` either because Passenger [*automatically* serves static files for you through Nginx](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/dev/ruby/rails_integration.html#static-assets-serving).

You should read [the official documentation](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was indeed in the `try_files`, just removing the line solves the issue. Slightly better and more readable solution would be:

```
location / {
    # nginx won't display 404, we leave this to Rails
    try_files $uri @passenger;
}

location @passenger {
   passenger_app_root /var/www/site;
   passenger_document_root /var/www/site/public;
   passenger_enabled on;
}
```

This was static files can be accessed without passing request to Passenger.

Comment: Passenger author here. Your config doesn't do anything that Passenger doesn't *already* do. Passenger *already* serves static files directly through Nginx without passing it to the app. This happens fully automatically without any configuration: https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/dev/ruby/rails_integration.html#static-assets-serving

Comment: Ok, thanks. There's a lot of magic in there, but in follows the convention over configuration principle.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer was more related to Passenger documentation. The main reason I stumbled upon this thread is that I was looking to migrate `Allow Override` setting of `.htaccess` to `nginx.conf`.

If you don't know much about nginx you would assume(*as I did*) that there must be a way to have `nginx.conf` per directory basis just like we have in Apache.

But that's not the way nginx implemented its settings system and the reason is that structure-wise they find central configurations better instead of having settings scattered over multiple files(.htaccess) making it tough to know the settings effective.

So, to migrating your settings from a `.htaccess` file, one has to copy those settings(*equivalent syntax of nginx*) over to single nginx.conf `Server{...}` block.

**Reference links:**

https://www.nginx.com/blog/converting-apache-to-nginx-rewrite-rules/

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-migrate-from-an-apache-web-server-to-nginx-on-an-ubuntu-vps