# Laravel - 404 Not Found

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

I just started using Laravel for the last few days and I have problem on URL routing, my `http://localhost:8017/laravel` looks good but `http://localhost:8017/laravel/foo` returns

> 404 Not Found

My OS Ubuntu 16.04, Laravel 5.4

**routes/web.php**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');    
});

// oedin
Route::get('foo', function () {
    return 'Hello World';
});
```

**nginx configuration**

```
server {
    listen 8017 default_server;
    listen [::]:8017 default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    #root /var/www/html;
    root /home/oedin/webdev;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        #try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        #fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        #fastcgi_index index.php;
        #fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        #include fastcgi_params;

    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}
}
```

Comment: Which page open when you hit on http://localhost:8017/laravel ?

Comment: Laravel welcome page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to serve your app with nginx, it's recommended to make a new nginx vhost configuration which contains your project root folder.

However life could be easier with `php artisan serve`, and no need to nginx server at this point .

Comment: wow `php artisan serve`.. that's work, how to make it http://localhost:8000/laravel/foo .. instead of http://localhost:8000/foo

Comment: You should add a route prefix for your routes https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#route-group-prefixes

Comment: `nginx vhost` and `route prefix` do the job ... thanks mate

Answer (score 1):

If you append index.php it will work I suppose.

```
http://localhost:8017/laravel/index.php/foo
```

Comment: that's weird have you changed anything in your index.php file under public dir?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is connected with server, You need something like mode overrite in Apache. In nginx theres no equlivment but try something like this

[How to convert Apache's `AllowOverride all` to nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35705641/how-to-convert-apaches-allowoverride-all-to-nginx)

Comment: previously I used Apache, but my pm decided to work with nginx

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Laravel', 'prefix' => 'laravel', 'middleware' => 'laravel'], function () {

    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');    
    });

    // oedin
    Route::get('foo', function () {
        return 'Hello World';
    });
});
```

You should run `php artisan` serv command in terminal

```
your URL like http://localhost:8000/laravel/foo
```

Hope this work for you !!!

Answer (score 0):

It might due to query error, like my case, tried to show error with error reporting, nothing in the log, but i try catch an error Exception in the query, got the SQL error..!

Hope this help,

Wrap the lines of code you wish to catch an exception on using try-catch statements

```
enter code here

try
{
//write your codes here
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
   dd($e->getMessage());
}
```

Do not forget to include the Exception class at the top of your controller by saying

Use Exception;

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same issue by doing bellow process

Copy .htaccess from `PUBLIC` folder to `ROUTE / MAIN` directory and run `PROJET` again