# Nginx not showing page laravel

Tags: laravel, nginx, apache2

when using Apache webserver we have in `apache2.conf`

```
AllowOverride All Allgranted
```

What is the alternative for Nginx webserver?

because always get the message 404 in Laravel

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert Apache's \`AllowOverride all\` to nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35705641/how-to-convert-apaches-allowoverride-all-to-nginx)

Answer (score 0):

AllowOverride is an Apache directive that allows using a local .htaccess file, which Laravel uses to set the uri rewrite rules for you app. Nginx doesn't use .htaccess files so you have to put the rewrite definition in your nginx site file instead.

These are the rewrite rules I use for my Laravel app

```
location / {
     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
   try_files $uri /index.php =404;
}
```

Comment: We only succeeded with try_files $ uri $ uri / / index.php$is_args$args; then it works with laravel